# Linux Packet Drops Increasing Over Time

Tags: linux, rhel, network-interface, ifconfig

I have Linux machine red-hat version 7.1 ( VM machine )

I see that dropped value increase every second!!!

Please advice how to find the problem , and if red-hat 7.1 need some patch update in order to resolve the problem.

```
ifconfig -a | grep drop | grep RX
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 20729  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0


    root@linux:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts # ifconfig -a | grep drop | grep RX
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 20735  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0


  root@linux:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts # ifconfig -a | grep drop | grep RX
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 20739  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0

    root@linux:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts # ifconfig -a | grep drop | grep RX
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 20743  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0


  root@linux:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts # ifconfig -a | grep drop | grep RX
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 20988  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0


 netstat -s | egrep "bad|err"
     0 bad segments received.
     0 packet receive errors
     0 receive buffer errors
     0 send buffer errors
```

Comment: You say that the VM is showing packet drops.  What's the host showing?  The problem might not be on the VM, but on the network.

Comment: what you mean - "What's the host showing" , what you want to check ?

Comment: from serverfault site "lain" recommended to install the patch --> unzip SF‐107601‐LS‐<version>_Solarflare_Linux_Utilities_RPM_64bit.zip  , what you think about this?

Comment: I sow also this link from red-hat https://access.redhat.com/solutions/657483 , but not sure if this help?

Comment: You say your RedHat is in a VM.  Therefore there must be a physical computer where this VM is running.  Does that show dropped packets?  Alternatively, do other VMs show dropped packets?

Comment: I checked that and no drop from esxi side